# Why is it so hard to share resource files (resx) with my Silverlight client?

Tags: silverlight, wcf-ria-services, resx

I'm trying to share a resource file (.resx file) from my web (RIA Service?Silverlight Host) to client (Silverlight) by linking the resource file into my client.  When I try to access resources using the `ResourceManager` object I get the following error:

```
System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException was caught
  Message=Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "PPCa.Modules.ProjectManager.Client.ViewModels.ResourceStrings.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "PPCa.Modules.ProjectManager.Client" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.
  StackTrace:
       at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String fileName)
       at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.GrovelForResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Dictionary`2 localResourceSets, Boolean tryParents, Boolean createIfNotExists, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo requestedCulture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
       at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo culture, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
       at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo culture)
       at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name)
       at PPCa.Modules.ProjectManager.Web.Helpers.ResourceHelper.GetEnumText[TResource](ProjectStatus a_projectStatus)
  InnerException:
```

**Edit:**

When I say I was linking the resource file, I mean I am using the 'Add as Link' option when adding the existing resx file to my project.

Comment: Is it because the SL project type uses a subset of the .NET framework and the RIA servie project type doesn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently working through this issue at the moment too. I have narrowed down the issue to namespaces. For me, I created a Silverlight Business Application and I wanted to rename the web project and change its namespace. As soon as I did this, the SL project became broken.

Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/silverlight4trainingcourse_sl4lob_07_event_administrator_dashboard_topic2.aspx#_Toc257811104) out. The notes on step 5 sort of explain the situation, but I'm currently trying to figure out a decent way around this.

EDIT: This worked for me: http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/184013/420509.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this worked for me also after creating the Silverlight Business Application and then attempting to change the namespaces.

Comment: The Silverlight forums link is broken, rendering this answer useless.

Answer (score 2):

A (questionable) solution was to:

1. copy (vice link) the resx files to the silverlight client.
2. add "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator" to the Custom Tool property to gen designer.cs file.
3. Opened designer.cs and changed the namespace back to that of the web designer.cs file.
4. Build solution to find/adjust related resx namespace issues.

It worked but I question the feasibility of having separate copies of resx files.  Other than having to ensure changes to the web resx files are manually duplicated to the silverlight client resx copies, are there any other potential pitfalls ... or is there an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Examine the Silverlight Business Application template (Create a new project, select the Silverlight Business Application template).

*.resx sharing is succesffully achieved in that project via Adding existing items as links -> In your Silverlight-side project, AddExisting item, Select your *.resx file, examine the 'Add' button, expand it and select the 'Add as link' option.

Comment: I know, that is the pattern that I'm emulating. This is taking place inside a plugin consisting of a RIA Services Class Library that is discovered through MEF by my primary application which is a Silverlight Business Application template.  And I am using the 'Add as link' option. Read the question.

Comment: Is your .resx file's code generation set to public ? (check Properties)

Comment: I'm using PublicResXFileCodeGenerator as a custom tool, if that's what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The add as link as solution, partially solves this problem, if I put a resources file ( added as link) in another folder that is not the one that the template created, you will receive this error again, you will have to put all your resources in the same Web\Resources folder if you  plan to use the template.
But what happen if you want to link other services with their own resources ( Ria services), well if I try any method till this day, and I still receive this freaking error